# How to move around UI elements and a normal game object together?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I am new to Unity and I find that the UI elements which reside under canvas are kind of confused to me. They use a different coordinate system than the ordinary game object, making its hard to put them to where you desire. The most confusing thing is after I make the UI elements be the children of a normal game object, I still can not drag them around together. Is there any simple and intuitive approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is the Canvas's Render Mode is set to "wold space"

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the UI elements use RectTransform and 'ordinary' gameObjects use Transform component(remember that ui elements are still gameObjects).

If you have issues manipulating them via script and want an easy way try using world space canvas:
create a canvas, select it and in inspector change his proprety to "world canvas", this will allow you to manipulate it like a normal gameObject and give his transform a parent.
Probably you will have to scale it a lot to respect dimensions rendered by camera.

unity tutorialhere https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html

Comment: Finally I find in my case I could use textmesh to achieve my goal.